# Accelerate the calculation of inv(X'*X)*Q*inv(X'*X) in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, linear-regression, matrix-inverse

I have to calculate Newey-West standard errors for large multiple regression models.

The final step of this calculation is to obtain

```
nwse = sqrt(diag(N.*inv(X'*X)*Q*inv(X'*X)));
```

This [file exchange contribution](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41275-newey-west-standard-errors) implements this as

```
nwse = sqrt(diag(N.*((X'*X)\Q/(X'*X))));
```

This looks reasonable, but in my case (5000x5000 sparse Q and X'*X) it's far too slow for my needs (about 30secs, I have to repeat this for about one million different models). Any ideas how to make this line faster?

Please note that I need only the diagonal, not the entire matrix and that both Q and (X'*X) are positive-definite.

Comment: Just a random try... Could you please evaluate the following expression and verify two things: 1. It gives the **same** result. 2. It improves the speed considerably. `((X'X)*((sparseinv(Q)*X')*X)*X`. Get `Sparseinv` from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33966-sparseinv-sparse-inverse-subset/content/sparseinv/sparseinv.m).
Also, you may try posting this question at math.stackexchange.com. Make sure you formulate it mathematically. There may be some techniques which may use the sparsity and positive definite properties.

Comment: @Robert P.: about every 100 models have the same X, so I can cache inv(X'*X) (any more elegant way to do it?)

Comment: Using `inv` is never the correct approach... I'll come back to you in a bit =) `X` is a vector right?

Comment: @Robert P.: X is a matrix. X'*X has the same dimensions as Q.

Comment: Another option is [choleskly decomposition](http://makarandtapaswi.wordpress.com/2011/07/08/cholesky-decomposition-for-matrix-inversion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can save a lot of computation time by explicitly doing an [LU factorization](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/lu.html), `[l, u, p, q] = lu(X'*X);` and use those factors when doing the calculations. Also, since `X` are constant for about 100 models, pre-calculating `X'*X` will most likely save you some time.

Note that in your case, the most time demanding operation might very well be the `sqrt`-function.

```
% Constant for every 100 models or so:
M = X'*X;
[l, u, p, q] = lu(M);

% Now, I guess this should be quite a bit faster (I might have messed up the order):
nwse = sqrt(diag(N.*(q * ( u \ (l \ (p * Q))) * q * (u \ (l \ p)))));
```

The first two terms are commonly used:

`l` the lower triangular matrix

`u` the upper triangular matrix

Now, `p` and `q` are a bit more uncommon.

`p` is a row permutation matrix used to obtain numerical stability. There is not much performance gain in doing `[l, u, p] = lu(M)` compared to `[l, u] = lu(M)` for sparse matrices.

`q` however offers a significant performance gain. `q` is a column permutation matrix that is used to reduce the amount of fill when doing the factorization.

Note that the `[l, u, p, q] = lu(M)` is only a valid syntax for sparse matrices.

---

As for why using full pivoting as described above should be faster:

Try the following to see the purpose of the column permutation matrix `q`. It is easier to work with elements that are aligned around the diagonal.

```
S = sprand(100,100,0.01);
[l, u, p] = lu(S);
spy(l)
figure
spy(u)
```

Now, compare it with this:

```
[ll, uu, pp, qq] = lu(S);
spy(ll);
figure
spy(uu);
```

<sup>Unfortunately, I don't have MATLAB here right now, so I can't guarantee that I put all the arguments in the correct order, but I think it's correct.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Following the helpful answer of Robert_P and the comments of Parag, I found the following to be the fastest for my particular large-scale sparse data:

```
L=chol(X'*X,'lower'); L=full(L);     
invXtX = L'\(L\ speye(size(X,2))); 
nwse = sqrt(N.*sum(invXtX.*(Q*invXtX)));
```

The last line computes the diagonal efficiently, idea taken [from here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/140285).

Comment: Why do you do : `L = full(L)`? Isn't it faster if you skip it?

Comment: It's strange, but it's slightly slower as a sparse matrix.

Comment: Hmm. it's not necessarily strange, it depends on the sparsity of the matrix. Representing a full matrix as a sparse one will be *very very* slow, so if the matrix isn't very sparse, I it's correct. I would guess the break-even point should be around 20% non-zero values, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Have you tried the following? Calculate `invXtX` using sparse matrices, and do `invXtX = full(invXtX)` afterwards. That is, only use full matrices when calculating the square root.

Comment: I tried it, but it wasn't better. I guess that L isn't so sparse, in my particular case.